# Onsen UI + listen for a click-and-hold on mobile

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Hi I know Onsen UI has the "ons-gesture-detector" but there is another way to listen for a hold event? 
I would like to avoid building a directive in AngularJS.
Tks for any reply.
David

Comment: I have build a calendar and I need to listen every long tap on every cell. I guess if I use "ons-gesture-detector" there will be problems about memory, because I have 2000 cells.

Answer (score 1):

`ons-gesture-detector` is based on [Hammer.JS](http://hammerjs.github.io/), which means that can be used without using the Angular directive.

For example, considering that the element in which you want to detect the `hold` action has `id="element"`, you code should be something like this.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("element");

var onHold = ons.GestureDetector(myElement).on("hold", function(event) {
  alert('hello!');
});
```

You can check [Hammer.JS documentation](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) for more info about the syntax. Just remember to replace `Hammer` with `ons.GestureDetector`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Complete Example for hold and release with onsen.io

Remember:

1 - hold reference to $interval so it can be cancelled on release

2 - pass reference to function in $interval that you want to run periodically

3 - pass milliseconds to $interval for time between your function firing.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    // interval var
    var holding;
    // hold myBtn
    ons.GestureDetector( document.getElementById('myBtn') ).on("hold", function(event) {
        // run $scope.myBtnLogic() every 150 millseconds
        // pass reference ($scope.myBtnLogic), not function call ( $scope.myBtnLogic() )
        holding = $interval($scope.myBtnLogic, 150);
    });
    // release of myBtn
    ons.GestureDetector( document.getElementById('myBtn') ).on("release", function(event) {
        // if there is a holding instance, cancel it
        // release event will fire even on normal clicks so need blocker.
        if(holding){ $interval.cancel(holding); }
    });
});
```